# Confusion with scaling down text in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

So I'd like to have one column of social media icons against the left side of the browser window (with the icons stacked) and then text that takes up 5 columns with the rest of the columns empty. This works fine when the browser window is large, but when I start making it smaller, the text then stretches all the way across instead of being constrained to the 5 columns and it moves below the icons. I would like the icon column to always take up one column next to the text. What am I missing to do this? I know I need to do `col-sm-x`, just can't make it work. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="row">
        <section class="social-media col-md-1">
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/neon.honey/" target="_blank">
                    <img class="media-object" src="../bootstrap/images/instagram.png" alt="Instagram">
                </a>            
                <a href="https://twitter.com/deephoney/" target="_blank">
                    <img class="media-object" src="../bootstrap/images/twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.pinterest.com/electrodextrose/" target="_blank">
                    <img class="media-object" src="../bootstrap/images/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" />
                </a>
                <a href="mailto:blahblahblah@gmail.com" target="_top">
                    <img class="media-object" src="../bootstrap/images/email.png" alt="Email me!" />            
                </a>
        </section>
        <section class="hello col-md-5 col-sm-">
            <h1>hello!</h1> 
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab libero, 
            cupiditate veniam officiis itaque in porro iure fugit iusto reprehenderit 
            commodi earum cum blanditiis quos error similique quod, facere! Hic.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
    color: rgb(244, 195, 197);
    font-family: 'Cookie', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(192,192,192,0.1);
    text-transform: lowercase;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    text-align: left;
    }

h3 {
    color: rgb(244, 195, 197);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.bgimage {
    background-image: url('../images/bgimage.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: rgb(34, 39, 42);
    padding-top: 25px;
}

h4 {
    margin-top: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
    }

.social-media {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.social-media img {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use `col-xs` when you want to preserve column ratio even in small screens.  When you only specify columns in `col-md` (f.e. `col-md-4`), bootstrap tells browser to keep 4 columns from the largest down to `md` screen size. After that (in `sm` and `xs` screen sizes) it will take 12.

So in your example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="row">
        <section class="social-media col-xs-1">
        ...
        </section>
        <section class="hello col-xs-5">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the col-md-1 and deal with the box your self .

I changed this part of your code

```
    .social-media {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }

    .social-media a {
        display: block;
    }
    .hello {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
```

and the results 
http://www.bootply.com/fsRThkzAV9